# Couchbase connection timeout with Java SDK

Tags: java, couchbase, nosql

I followed the couchbase tutorial to connect to remote couchbase server, but it failed on connection time out after I try to open default bucket.

I have checked that I can open couchbase server page on my computer(192.xx.xx.xx:8091)

Here is my Java code

```
CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
            .queryEnabled(true)
            .build();
Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(env,"192.xx.xx.xx:8091");

Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("default","");
JsonObject user = JsonObject.empty()
        .put("firstname", "Walter")
        .put("lastname", "White")
        .put("job", "chemistry teacher")
        .put("age", 50);

JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.create("walter", user);
JsonDocument response = bucket.upsert(doc);

JsonDocument walter = bucket.get("walter");
System.out.println("Found: " + walter);

cluster.disconnect();
```

And the console

```
com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseCore <init>
CouchbaseEnvironment: {sslEnabled=false, sslKeystoreFile='null', sslKeystorePassword='null', queryEnabled=true, queryPort=8093, bootstrapHttpEnabled=true, bootstrapCarrierEnabled=true, bootstrapHttpDirectPort=8091, bootstrapHttpSslPort=18091, bootstrapCarrierDirectPort=11210, bootstrapCarrierSslPort=11207, ioPoolSize=4, computationPoolSize=4, responseBufferSize=16384, requestBufferSize=16384, kvServiceEndpoints=1, viewServiceEndpoints=1, queryServiceEndpoints=1, ioPool=NioEventLoopGroup, coreScheduler=CoreScheduler, eventBus=DefaultEventBus, packageNameAndVersion=couchbase-java-client/2.1.4 (git: 2.1.4), dcpEnabled=false, retryStrategy=BestEffort, maxRequestLifetime=75000, retryDelay=ExponentialDelay{growBy 1.0 MICROSECONDS; lower=100, upper=100000}, reconnectDelay=ExponentialDelay{growBy 1.0 MILLISECONDS; lower=32, upper=4096}, observeIntervalDelay=ExponentialDelay{growBy 1.0 MICROSECONDS; lower=10, upper=100000}, keepAliveInterval=30000, autoreleaseAfter=2000, bufferPoolingEnabled=true, queryTimeout=75000, viewTimeout=75000, kvTimeout=2500, connectTimeout=5000, disconnectTimeout=25000, dnsSrvEnabled=false}

com.couchbase.client.core.node.CouchbaseNode$1 call
Connected to Node 192.xx.xx.xx
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.couchbase.client.java.util.Blocking.blockForSingle(Blocking.java:93)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster.openBucket(CouchbaseCluster.java:108)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster.openBucket(CouchbaseCluster.java:99)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster.openBucket(CouchbaseCluster.java:89)
    at HelloCouchbase.main(HelloCouchbase.java:19)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    ... 5 more
```

Using couchbase server 4

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to the article https://forums.couchbase.com/t/unable-to-connect-to-db-java-util-concurrent-timeoutexception/4471/3

The problem is solved.

It need to add longer connectTimeout as below

```
CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
                    .connectTimeout(10000) // 10000ms = 10s, default is 5s
                    .queryEnabled(true).build();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are like me who likes jvm switches in certain cases,
you can do the following.

```
java -Xms1g -Xmx4g -Dspring.profiles.active=local -Dcom.couchbase.connectTimeout=60000 <program>
```

https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.7/client-settings.html

all client settings can be specified with prefix "com.couchbase"