# Couchbase concurrent timeout exception : Java SDK

Tags: java, couchbase

I am working with java in a maven project. I was using couchbase 2.3.1 but in trying to resolve this issue I rolled back to 2.2.8 to no avail.

The issue I get is that while I do get date through to my couchbase cluster I am seeing alot of this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at com.couchbase.client.java.util.Blocking.blockForSingle(Blocking.java:75)
at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.upsert(CouchbaseBucket.java:359)
at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.upsert(CouchbaseBucket.java:354)
```

Below are the settings for my couchbase environment:

```
CouchbaseEnvironment: {sslEnabled=false, sslKeystoreFile='null', sslKeystorePassword='null', queryEnabled=false, queryPort=8093, bootstrapHttpEnabled=true, bootstrapCarrierEnabled=true, bootstrapHttpDirectPort=8091, bootstrapHttpSslPort=18091, bootstrapCarrierDirectPort=11210, bootstrapCarrierSslPort=11207, ioPoolSize=24, computationPoolSize=24, responseBufferSize=16384, requestBufferSize=16384, kvServiceEndpoints=1, viewServiceEndpoints=1, queryServiceEndpoints=1, searchServiceEndpoints=1, ioPool=NioEventLoopGroup, coreScheduler=CoreScheduler, eventBus=DefaultEventBus, packageNameAndVersion=couchbase-java-client/2.2.8 (git: 2.2.8, core: 1.2.9), dcpEnabled=false, retryStrategy=BestEffort, maxRequestLifetime=75000, retryDelay=ExponentialDelay{growBy 1.0 MICROSECONDS, powers of 2; lower=100, upper=100000}, reconnectDelay=ExponentialDelay{growBy 1.0 MILLISECONDS, powers of 2; lower=32, upper=4096}, observeIntervalDelay=ExponentialDelay{growBy 1.0 MICROSECONDS, powers of 2; lower=10, upper=100000}, keepAliveInterval=30000, autoreleaseAfter=2000, bufferPoolingEnabled=true, tcpNodelayEnabled=true, mutationTokensEnabled=false, socketConnectTimeout=1000, dcpConnectionBufferSize=20971520, dcpConnectionBufferAckThreshold=0.2, dcpConnectionName=dcp/core-io, callbacksOnIoPool=false, queryTimeout=75000, viewTimeout=75000, kvTimeout=2500, connectTimeout=5000, disconnectTimeout=25000, dnsSrvEnabled=false}
```

Im not really too sure what to look at here. As far as I can tell there should be a decent enough connection between the server where the app is running and the couchbase cluster. Any help or direction on this would be helpful. Here is a snippet from where the error is being thrown.

```
LockableItem<InnerVertex> lv = this.getInnerVertex(id);
lv.lock();
    try {
        String content;
        try {
            content = mapper.writeValueAsString(lv.item);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            LOG.warning(e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        RawJsonDocument d = RawJsonDocument.create(VertexId.toKey(id), content);
        bucket.upsert(d);
    } finally {
        lv.unlock();
    }
```

Comment: did you try increasing timeout ? It can be a slow network issue.

Answer (score 13):

I was searching for the answer. I got there are many solutions all are talking about exception. I also checked the jar code, it is called that it is timeout exception.

### Root Cause Analysis

The error occured from the following section of couchbase: https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/java/util/Blocking.java#L71

```
public static <T> T blockForSingle(final Observable<? extends T> observable, final long timeout,
    final TimeUnit tu) {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    TrackingSubscriber<T> subscriber = new TrackingSubscriber<T>(latch);

    observable.subscribe(subscriber);

    try {
        if (!latch.await(timeout, tu)) { // From here, this error occurs.
            throw new RuntimeException(new TimeoutException());
        }
}
```

> If the timeout kicks in, a TimeoutException nested in a
>   RuntimeException is thrown to be fully compatible with the
>   Observable.timeout(long, TimeUnit) behavior.

### Resource Link:

http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.2.0/com/couchbase/client/java/util/Blocking.html

### Your configuration analysis and solution:

Your couchbase environment connectionTimeout is `5000ms` or 5sec, which is the default value of connection timeout.

You need to increase this value to `10000ms or greater`. Your problem will be solved.

```
//this tunes the SDK (to customize connection timeout)
CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
        .connectTimeout(10000) //10000ms = 10s, default is 5s
        .build();
```

### A full Solution

[Simonbasle](https://forums.couchbase.com/users/simonbasle) has given a full solution in this tutorial:

> From the short log, it looks like the SDK is able to connect to the
>   node, but takes a little much time to open the bucket. How good is the
>   network link between the two machines? Is this a VM/cloud machine?
>
> What you can try to do is increase the connect timeout:

```
public class NoSQLTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //this tunes the SDK (to customize connection timeout)
            CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
                    .connectTimeout(10000) //10000ms = 10s, default is 5s
                    .build();
            System.out.println("Create connection");
            //use the env during cluster creation to apply
            Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(env, "10.115.224.94");
            System.out.println("Try to openBucket");
            Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("beer-sample"); //you can also force a greater timeout here (cluster.openBucket("beer-sample", 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            System.out.println("disconnect");
            cluster.disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> As a side note, you should always reuse the CouchbaseEnvironment,
>   CouchbaseCluster and Bucket instances once created (usually by making
>   them public static somewhere, or a Spring singleton, etc...). These
>   are thread safe and should be shared (and they are expensive to create
>   anyway).

### Resource Link:

1. [Couchbase connection timeout with Java SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605233/couchbase-connection-timeout-with-java-sdk)

Comment: is there a jvm switch for timeout?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the question, and for @SkyWalker's Answer. 
They helped when I encountered this annoying timeout.

For Spring Data Couchbase 2, adding the following to application.properties solved it

```
spring.couchbase.env.timeouts.connect=20000
```